# Intellij IDEA parse custom bean - cannot find custom handler for namespace

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

```
<camel:camelContext id="myCamelContext">
    <camel:routeBuilder ref="route"/>
</camel:camelContext>
```

I try to parse the bean above in Intellij IDEA ("Parse custom bean"), but get the following error:

> Cannot find custom handler for namespace 'http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring'

The IDE also displays an error for any corresponding `@Autowired` annotations in my test code, although the tests run successfully. The application works at runtime, and I have camel-spring as a maven dependency. It only has problems in the IDE.

Answer (score 4):

The camel-spring maven dependency was at "runtime" scope. While technically this is correct, this made it unavailable to Intellij when coding. Changing the maven scope to "compile" enabled Intellij to use the the camel spring bean handler for interpreting the bean.

Comment: I've created a ticket for that bug: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-121876, thanks for self-diagnostics!